# Exact calculations in python

Tags: python

I am using Python for calculations.

However, I faced the inaccuracies in calculations.

Thus, `0.7+0.1=0.79999`, etc. (`float`)

May anyone suggest a way for exact calculations?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: please check this http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Which version of python are you running? You can round the number using the function round()

Comment: No, I need precision E-11

Comment: That's not what it should be marked as duplicated of. It sounds more like OP is searching for `Decimal("0.7") + Decimal("0.1")` which would correctly result in `0.8`.

Comment: Yes, but I have to write Decimal() everywhere! For all variables, and for operations over them.

Comment: I don't at all see the problem. You equally have to use a keyboard to be able to type on a computer. That's not an inconvenience.

Comment: Ok, I'll try...

Comment: Why in c=Decimal(a)*Decimal(b) the variable c is not Decimal?

Comment: Maybe it helps you `round(0.7+0.1, 11)`. This produces 0.8.